# Obtaining single line of a JSON response, using either Json.Parse or Regex in C#

Tags: c#, json, regex, string, speech-to-text

I am a Junior Java developer and not too great with C#, so I would like some help in solving a problem. What I am trying to do is use existing code shared on github that takes a microphone input, uploads it to the Google Speech-to-Text API, and then returns JSON response with the transcript. This part is all working fine.

What isnt working, is storing the value of the "Transcript:" returned in the JSON into a string variable.

I have tried to do this multiple ways, I have looked for ways to convert the JSON response to an object using SimpleJSON and Newtonsoft, and I have also tried using a regular expression to read the JSON line that starts with "transcript." I saw an example of what I wanted done (linked below) but I was getting compiler errors. If someone could either help me with this, or point me to a better result I would appreciate it.

Here is the code I am using.

// Acquired from https://github.com/steelejay/LowkeySpeech

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;


[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]

public class GoogleVoiceSpeech : MonoBehaviour {

    public GUIText TextBox;

    struct ClipData {
        public int samples;
    }

    const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

    private int minFreq;
    private int maxFreq;

    private bool micConnected = false;

    //A handle to the attached AudioSource
    private AudioSource goAudioSource;

    public string apiKey;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        //Check if there is at least one microphone connected
        if (Microphone.devices.Length <= 0) {
            //Throw a warning message at the console if there isn't
            Debug.LogWarning("Microphone not connected!");
        } else //At least one microphone is present
          {
            //Set 'micConnected' to true
            micConnected = true;

            //Get the default microphone recording capabilities
            Microphone.GetDeviceCaps(null, out minFreq, out maxFreq);

            //According to the documentation, if minFreq and maxFreq are zero, the microphone supports any frequency...
            if (minFreq == 0 && maxFreq == 0) {
                //...meaning 44100 Hz can be used as the recording sampling rate
                maxFreq = 44100;
            }

            //Get the attached AudioSource component
            goAudioSource = this.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        }
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        //If there is a microphone
        if (micConnected) {
            //If the audio from any microphone isn't being recorded
            if (!Microphone.IsRecording(null)) {
                //Case the 'Record' button gets pressed
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 - 25, 200, 50), "Record")) {
                    //Start recording and store the audio captured from the microphone at the AudioClip in the AudioSource
                    goAudioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 7, maxFreq); //Currently set for a 7 second clip
                }
            } else //Recording is in progress
              {

                //Case the 'Stop and Play' button gets pressed
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 - 25, 200, 50), "Stop and Play!")) {
                    float filenameRand = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.0f, 10.0f);

                    string filename = "testing" + filenameRand;

                    Microphone.End(null); //Stop the audio recording

                    Debug.Log("Recording Stopped");

                    if (!filename.ToLower().EndsWith(".wav")) {
                        filename += ".wav";
                    }

                    var filePath = Path.Combine("testing/", filename);
                    filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filePath);
                    Debug.Log("Created filepath string: " + filePath);

                    // Make sure directory exists if user is saving to sub dir.
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
                    SavWav.Save(filePath, goAudioSource.clip); //Save a temporary Wav File
                    Debug.Log("Saving @ " + filePath);
                    //Insert your API KEY here.
                    string apiURL = "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?&key=AIzaSyAV65cThBBZAqmzW7MbWaccybtBrwY4Udc";
                    string Response;

                    Debug.Log("Uploading " + filePath);
                    Response = HttpUploadFile(apiURL, filePath, "file", "audio/wav; rate=44100");
                    Debug.Log("Response String: " + Response);

                    var jsonresponse = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(Response);

                    if (jsonresponse != null) {
                        string resultString = jsonresponse["result"][0].ToString();
                        var jsonResults = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(resultString);

                        string transcripts = jsonResults["alternative"][0]["transcript"].ToString();

                        Debug.Log("transcript string: " + transcripts);
                        TextBox.text = transcripts;

                    }
                    //goAudioSource.Play(); //Playback the recorded audio

                    File.Delete(filePath); //Delete the Temporary Wav file

                }

                GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 + 25, 200, 50), "Recording in progress...");
            }
        } else // No microphone
          {
            //Print a red "Microphone not connected!" message at the center of the screen
            GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 - 25, 200, 50), "Microphone not connected!");
        }
    }

    public string HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType) {

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Uploading {0} to {1}", file, url));

        Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        String file64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes,
                                         Base64FormattingOptions.None);

        Debug.Log(file64);

        try {

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) {




                string json = "{ \"config\": { \"languageCode\" : \"en-US\" }, \"audio\" : { \"content\" : \"" + file64 + "\"}}";

                Debug.Log(json);
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Debug.Log(httpResponse);

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.Log("Response:" + result);

            }

        }
        catch (WebException ex) {
            var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            Debug.Log(resp);

        }


        return "empty";

    }

}
```

I am getting back the correct console message with the JSON result. I just need to get the "transcript" value into a String. Here is a sample of the response from the Google API.

```
Response:{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "this is a test",
          "confidence": 0.98762906
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The actual creator of the SimpleJSON framework responded to someone with a similar issue a few years back, but when I try to implement a similar fix, I get errors because my response is singular.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1443367/get-json-array-object-string-value.html

I would appreciate anyone help or guidance with this. I have been looking online for a few days trying to get this working, and asked co-workers (who couldn't help me due to their inexperience with C#) before posting here.

Comment: Is there any way you might be able to boil that down into a [mcve], showing where the specific problem is in your code?

Comment: Is the main question just how to get transcript property (string) from the array of alternatives in the json?

Comment: @Noel Yes the main question is how to get the transcript string from the array of alternatives in the Json. (I may have put too much info in my question, but I wanted to be thorough) In the example the transcript says "this is a test" I want to have that stored in a variable.

Comment: @dbc Part of the problem is I am not sure where to even properly put my code within the existing, depending on the method I put my code in, the program might lock up or return null. The entire code I posted works in showing the Json in the console successfully, all i want to do is take the transcript and store it in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newtonsoft is a better choice and I'll walk you through how to use it.

First, [create the C# classes](https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-you-can-automatically-create-classes-from-json-or-xml-in-visual-studio/) you'll need to hold the result of the parsing.  In your example, they will look like this:

```
public class SpeechResponse
{
    public Result[] results { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Alternative[] alternatives { get; set; }
}

public class Alternative
{
    public string transcript { get; set; }
    public float confidence { get; set; }
}
```

You already know how to obtain the JSON data, so let's assume it's been saved in  `String json`.  You can turn the string into the C# classes with this command:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpeechResponse>( json );
```

And the specific piece of data that you're looking for can be obtained like this:

```
string phrase = response.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
```

---

**Bonus Tip**
If you're using Visual Studio, you can easily create the class definitions by copying the JSON example data and selecting "Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes" ([Read More](https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-you-can-automatically-create-classes-from-json-or-xml-in-visual-studio/)).

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly for me, I guess using Newtonsoft was much easier. It was much cleaner than other approaches I tried. I voted you UP, but because I am a noob it doesn't affect the rating publicly. Thanks for teaching me something!

Comment: You're very welcome.  If it will let you mark my answer as "accepted", that's the best way to let everyone know your issue is resolved.

Comment: Perfect, this was my first post, so learning these kinds of things are helpful.